# How to execute code after an instance is initialised using the synthesised init(from decoder:) method?

Tags: ios, swift, decoding, codable

If I have a struct called `Person`

```
struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String
}
```

I want it to print "Person initialised" every time a `Person` is initialised using the synthesised `init(from decoder:)` method which comes automatically when you conform to `Codable`. Is there any way to get this behaviour without implementing a custom `init(from decoder:)` method? Sort of "appending" code to execute after the synthesised `init(from decoder:)` is called.

In essence something like:

```
protocol Announce: Codable { }

extension Announce {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        try self.init(from: decoder)  // I want this to call the synthesised one you get by conforming to Codable, NOT itself
        print("Person initialised using synthesised init")
    }
}
```

The reason I don't want to implement my own initialiser is because I don't want to rewrite everything the compiler is already going to do for me for free just to add a simple `print("Person initialised")`, specially if the `struct` becomes more complex.

Please let me know if I can achieve this sort of behaviour without providing my own implementation of `init(from decoder:)`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Very reasonable but, I believe, not possible, exactly because of the way the initializer is synthesized and injected for you. It's all or nothing: you accept the synthesized implementation or you write your own. You are imagining a sort of "inheritance" or "delegation" that just doesn't exist.

Comment: But that particular init is only used when decoding so you always know when Person objects are created with that init, when you do JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self,…) (or similar)